# Redirect to public folder when using ZF2

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2 (Zend Framework 2, v2.2) and I would like that http://www.foo.com/path/to/app/ redirect to the public folder.

I've tried a lot of solution but not of them allow the url to point to /path/to/app/public/index.php, while only displaying /path/to/app/.

I would appreciate any solution as I cannot create a virtual host as described in app skeleton README file.

Any help very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Greg.

Comment: Just a question, www.foo.com redirects also to your zf2 app ? Otherwise if you use apache2, try with one virtual host.

Comment: No, http://www.foo.com/path/to/app/ only redirects to zf2 app. That is why the virtual host wouldn't work. Also the hosting I'm planning on using would not allow to use the virtual host.

Comment: But ANY host basically would allow for you to setup domains or subdomains to be routed to a specific folder. Have then all route into the folder `public` and you're basically done. The virtualHost wouldn't do anything else. And if that's not the case: consider a different host, don't support bad quality providers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just set up a Virtual Host?

```
DocumentRoot "actual/path/to/application"
ServerName appname
```

this would mean that when you type

```
http://yourdomain.com/appname it will resolve to http://root/actual/path/to/application
```

Maybe I am not understanding the problem properly - but i would use a VirtualHost instead of complex Mod_Rewrite rules.

Comment: The issue is that you don't always want to access your application as a subdomain. That might be appropriate for development purposes (i.e. zend-app.dev), but not for deployment. The ZF2 tutorial assumes that you'll be fine with it being a subdomain, or the domain itself in the live environment which isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a solution: https://github.com/gpfister/ZendSkeletonApplication

In short, I added a .htaccess file at the root of the application:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If URL to the application is http://foo.com/path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
# the set the base to /path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/
RewriteBase /path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

And then I changed module/Application/config/module.config.php.

It is now working fine, though http://foo.com/path/to/ZendSkeletonApplication/public will fail, which is fine as I don't plan to access the app with this URL.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is actually not saving my problem... so I rules it differently... I use a local web server and configure virtual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache with mod rewrite Stick this in your htaccess found above your public folder (/path/to/app)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. Instead, http://localhost/path/to/app/ displays me the content of the folder at /path/to/app/.